# MySQL Python Query matching row name with column name

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

I'm building a software to combine some chemicals into different compounds (each compound can have 1,2,3 or 4 chemicals), but some chemicals cannot combine with some other chemicals.

I have a table in my mysql db that has the following columns:
chemical_id,chemicalName, and one column for each chemical in my list.
Each row has one of the chemicals. the value in the fields tell me if both these chemicals can go together in a compound, or not (1, or 0). So all chemicals have a row, and a column. They were created in the same order, too. Here (dummy data): https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxC4L.jpg

I have a python list of chemicals_ids, which I'm gonna combine with themselves to make compounds of 1,2,3 and 4 chems, but I need a function to determine if any two of them ain't compatible.

I was trying to mess around with INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMN_NAME but I'm kinda lost.
A loop around something like this would work, but the syntax won't.

```
list_of_chemicals = ['ChemName1','ChemName2','ChemName3'] #etc
def verify_comp(a,b): #will be passed with chem names
mycursor.execute("SELECT chemicalName FROM chemical_compatibility WHERE chemical_id = 'ChemName1' AND 'ChemName2' = 0")
#etc
```

I have tried to use %s placeholders but it seems only to work in certain parts of mysql query. I'm a beginner both at Python and SQL so any light will be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Normalize your data structure - You must have junction table which refers to substances table twice if they're compatible (or all pairs and a column with the compatibility value).

Comment: Yeah I had 4 different tables for different kinds of compatibility. I now have a junction table which has chemical_id1, chemical_id2 (both deriving from single id on single chemicals table), and one column for each kind of compatibility (0-1). Thanks @Akina!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed @Akina's suggestion and made a new table containing pairs of chemicals and compatibility value for each pair.

I also learned that apart from placeholders %s, which can only be used for values on python cursor sql execute statements, you can use a py variable too by doing something like this:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM "+variablename+" WHERE condition = 1")
```

I'm not worried about SQL Injection for this project nor do I know if what I say here is 100% correct, but maybe it can help people that are lost nevertheless.